# How can I calculate predictor coefficients in linear prediction model in R?

Tags: r

I'm quite new to R and I have the following problem:

I have a time series / signal and I want to build [linear prediction model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_prediction). It seems something like Matlab [lpc](http://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/lpc.html) will be great but I can't find corresponding function in R. Which package should I use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you're talking about an autoregressive (AR) model - Yule-Walker equations seem to be at the heart of what you linked to. In which case, the `ar` function in the basic R installation may suffice or for more complicated models the `arima` function, also in the basic installation.

You should also look at the [Time Series Task View](http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/TimeSeries.html) on CRAN for additional information on suitable packages and I recommend you consult it for further options.

Answer (score 2):

The kind of analysis you are trying to to can be done using packages in the [timeseries task view](http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/TimeSeries.html). Most likely you want some kind of Autoregressive model (AR), for which I refer to the `Forecasting and Univariate Modeling` section of that task view. The linear filtering method you mentioned is probably implemented in packages like `robfilter`, more info can be found in the `Decomposition and Filtering` section of the task view.